# How to select date from date picker in VBA selenium webdriver

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to insert date in the date field by using selenium VBA web driver, the date field is not a free text field, I have to select calendar to insert the date.
I can click on calendar icon by using this command

```
   .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='jscal_trigger_cf_898']").Click
```

how to select date (07-01-2019) in the calendar

HTML Code:

```
                            <img src="themes/corporate/images/btnL3Calendar.gif" id="jscal_trigger_cf_898">         

            <!--add ended-->



                                <br><font size="1"><em old="(yyyy-mm-dd)">(dd-mm-yyyy)</em></font>

            <!--added by Nirbhay 27-03-2017 for restricted field editing-->
                            <script type="text/javascript" id="massedit_calendar_cf_898">
                Calendar.setup ({
                    inputField : "jscal_field_cf_898", ifFormat : "%d-%m-%Y", showsTime : false, button : "jscal_trigger_cf_898", singleClick : true, step : 1
                })
            </script>
            <!--add ended-->
        </td>
```

[image]

Thanks,

Ravikumar

Comment: html code:<img src="themes/corporate/images/btnL3Calendar.gif" id="jscal_trigger_cf_898">

Comment: @QHarr, I have added code please check

Comment: Hummm...is this a public url? I suspect not. What I can see from the above is it appears there is an element you can click on to increment the date in what are, I assume, steps of 1 day..  That seems inefficient and I am guessing there are other methods for date selection - is there an input element for entering a date?

Comment: @QHarr the only option is select date from calendar

Comment: if you right click inspect on the number 7 shown what does the html show?